# How do I prevent the use of mocks on certain tests but use it on others?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have written three Jest unit tests and I am mocking a function. This mock is used for two unit tests but my third one fails since it needs to access the real code. If I comment out the mock, then the first two tests fail and third one passes. I tried using beforeAll and beforeEach methods where I disable the mock only for the third test but haven't had any success. I'd appreciate any help!

ReactErrorBoundary.tsx:

```
import { render, act, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import ReactErrorBoundary from '../../components/ReactErrorBoundary';
import { ErrorBoundary } from 'react-error-boundary';
import { logger } from '../../services/logService';

jest.mock('../../services/logService', () => ({
  logger: jest.fn(),
}));

jest.mock('react-error-boundary', () => {
  const ErrorPage = require('../../components/ErrorPage').default;

  return {
    ...jest.requireActual('react-error-boundary'),
    ErrorBoundary: jest.fn(({ onError, onReset, FallbackComponent }) => {
      onError && onError(new Error());
      onReset && onReset();

      return {
        FallbackComponent: ErrorPage,
      };
    }),
  };
});

describe('ReactErrorBoundary with mocked ErrorBoundary', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    jest.mock('react-error-boundary', () => {
      const ErrorPage = require('../../components/ErrorPage').default;

      return {
        ...jest.requireActual('react-error-boundary'),
        ErrorBoundary: jest.fn(({ onError, onReset, FallbackComponent }) => {
          onError && onError(new Error());
          onReset && onReset();

          return {
            FallbackComponent: ErrorPage,
          };
        }),
      };
    });
  });

  test('renders ErrorBoundary with ErrorPage as FallbackComponent', () => {
    render(<ReactErrorBoundary />);
    expect(ErrorBoundary).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        FallbackComponent: expect.any(Function),
        onError: expect.any(Function),
        onReset: expect.any(Function),
        children: undefined,
      }, {});            
  });

  test('passes children to ErrorBoundary', () => {
    const children = <div>Hello World</div>;

    render(<ReactErrorBoundary>{children}</ReactErrorBoundary>);
    expect(ErrorBoundary).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      FallbackComponent: expect.any(Function),
      onError: expect.any(Function),
      onReset: expect.any(Function),
      children: <div>Hello World</div>,
    }, {});  
  });
});

describe('ReactErrorBoundary without mocked ErrorBoundary', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    jest.unmock('react-error-boundary');
  });

  test('logs error message when onError is triggered', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log').mockImplementation();

    render(
      <ReactErrorBoundary>
        <ChildComponentWithError />
      </ReactErrorBoundary>
    );

    expect(spy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Error caught!');

    expect(logger).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(logger).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.any(Error));

    spy.mockRestore();
  });
});

const ChildComponentWithError = () => {
  throw new Error('Test Error');
};
```